# Yandex Maps, расстояние между двумя точками на PHP

Tags: php, xml, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Для Yandex Maps данный метод существует только в JS API, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать на PHP?
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/ICoordSystem-docpage/#getDistance
Быть может возможно получить как то ответ через XML-запросы?

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем от Яндекса буду использовать только координаты.
Решение здесь 
https://www.kobzarev.com/programming/calculation-of-distances-between-cities-on-their-coordinates/